# Is it possible to Calculate This integral using fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

I am trying to calculate $$\displaystyle\int\limits^{\cssId{upper-bound-mathjax}{\infty}}_{\cssId{lower-bound-mathjax}{-\infty}} \dfrac{x^2}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)\left(x^2+b^2\right)}\,\cssId{int-var-mathjax}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
for $a,b >0$

I recognize that I can split it to multiply of the derivative of $\frac{ln(x^2+a^2)}{2}$ and $\frac{ln(x^2+b^2)}{2}$ but I am stuck on calculate transform Fourier of the $ln$ function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use
$$\dfrac{x^2}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)\left(x^2+b^2\right)}=\frac1 {a^2-b^2}\Bigg[\frac {a^2}{x^2+a^2}-\frac {b^2}{x^2+b^2} \Bigg]$$

Comment: True, I didn't think on that. still I would like to see the technique with transform fourier since that was the purpose of this specific exercise

Comment: @Sagigever. I think that this help also for Fourier transform.

Comment: I am not sure I can see how, should I apply plancherel equality?

Comment: Multiply the integrand by $e^{-i\omega x}$, evaluate the integral as a Fourier Transform (use table lookups, properties, etc.), and then evaluate the result at $\omega = 0$.